# Multidimensional array sum

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, multidimensional-array, delegates

I have this :

- Cat = 1 Dog = 2 Mouse = 4 House = 8 Ball = 16 Music = 32

And if i am getting an value from SQL = 3 -I want the output as "Cat, Dog"
If value = 7 then "Cat, Dog, Mouse"
and soo on.

Any help?

Comment: This is soo confusing!

Comment: This would make more sense if you were dealing with a flag enum, I think.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use linq where to check if the number is less or equal to the specified value.

```
Dictionary<int, string> wordList = new Dictionary<int, string> {
            {1, "Cat"},
            {2, "Dog"},
            {4, "Mouse"},
            {8, "House"},
            {16, "Ball"},
            {32, "Music"},
        };

        int number = 7;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> word in 
            wordList.Where(pair => pair.Key <= number)) {
            builder.Append(word.Value);
            builder.Append(", ");
        }
```

Comment: Less than unfortunately doesn't work in this case. If `valueFromSQL = 6` it should arguably not print Cat.

Comment: Thanks Lambda, works fine if i give odd numbers, but when i give 2 or 8 gives me back only Cat, Dog, Mouse. Need 8=House

Comment: Thanks @user2778395, I changed it from less than to less than or equal to it will work.

Answer (score 2):

http://ideone.com/aPqPqE

```
[System.Flags]
enum Things { Cat = 1, Dog = 2, Mouse = 4, House = 8, Ball = 16, Music = 32 }

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {

        var value = Things.Cat | Things.Dog;

        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
     }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Never knew about this.

Comment: Wow, who would downvote this answer? And why wasn't it accepted? Did one of the two other posters actually downvote to promote their (relatively low quality) answer? Needlessly to say, the accepted answer is pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have `enum Item = { Cat = 1, ... }`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(Item i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Item))) 
    if ((valueFromSQL & ((int)i)) != 0) {
        if (sb.Length > 0)
            sb.Append(", ");
        sb.Append(i);
    }

string result = sb.ToString();
```

This handles zero and single values (eg. `valueFromSQL = 4`) correctly. It works because the bit representation of the values are the following:

```
Name          Decimal   Binary

Cat           1         ...0001
Dog           2         ...0010
Mouse         4         ...0100
valueFromSQL  3         ...0011
```

Notice each `Item` value uses only a single unique bit. When you add these values, you effectively OR the bits together. Thus we can use bitwise AND to test whether the bit for a specific value is non-zero.

Comment: @nietaki I think you would still need to specify the values. IIRC C# just uses sequential integers.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain?